# Iterate Through array inside object

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays, regex

Using C# regex i have sent modelState object to the java script and add it in the var type temp. Now this object have multiple arrays with in.

[image]

One way is to specify the key and get all error msgs from this object like

```
{{modelState["employee.FirstName"][0]}}
{{modelState["employee.Email"][0]}}
{{modelState[".............."][0]}}
```

There are almost 8 to 10 key pairs that maybe returns and will take time to write all key value. How do i iterate from this arrays inside object and get all the errors with out specifying the key value.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xyxwhys8/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could:

```
var allErrors = [];
$.each( modelState, function( name, errors ){
    allErrors = allErrors.concat(errors); 
} );
```